# Decidability of whether $w \in L(M_1) \setminus L(M_2)$

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, proof-techniques

I'm studying for my finals and I came across this question from past exams:

> Is the following language decidable?
> $$ L = \{ \langle M_1,M_2,w \rangle \mid w \in L(M_1) \setminus L(M_2) \}. $$

How can I be sure of my answer? Is there any way to know for sure?

Comment: The way we know for sure in mathematics is by *proving* things.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, $L$ is not decidable as given $\langle M_1, M_2, w\rangle$ we need to decide whether

1. $w\in L(M_1)$, and
2. $w\in \overline{L(M_2)}$.

The first condition smells like deciding the language $A_{TM} = \{ \langle M, w \rangle: \text{ $M$ accepts $w$}\}$, and the second condition smells like deciding $\overline{A_{TM}}$. To make sure that the intuition got it right, you need to **prove formally** undecidability for $L$, here is a hint.

**Hint:** show that there is a reduction from some undecidable language to $L$. It is sufficient to capture the hardness of one the above conditions. Thus, to make things simpler, think how you can fix one of the machines $M_1$ or $M_2$ in the reduction's output, so that one of the conditions holds trivially. I leave the rest to you.